# document.getElementById(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to run a test using jest and enzyme, but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

or:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
 var el = document.getElementById('myTable');
 var firstHeader =  document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName( 'thead' )[0].getElementsByTagName( 'tr' )[0].getElementsByTagName( 'th' )[0];

dragger.on('drop',(from, to, el) => {
 this.props.onHeaderDrop(
 document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName( 'thead' )[0].getElementsByTagName( 'tr' )[0].getElementsByClassName('handle')[from].getAttribute('id'),
```

I tried to add the following right before mounting my component:

```
  const elementMock = { addEventListener: jest.fn() };
  jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockImplementation(() => elementMock);
```

Or maybe should I add anything on my prop :  this.props.onHeaderDrop ?

Comment: It seems as if `document.getElementById('myTable')` cannot find an element by this `ID` and therefore returns `null`. Make sure your element is actually mounted.

Comment: I believe it is, its rendering correct with all of my props. Problem is when I try to test an event, error is pointing out to my set state now

Answer (score 0):

try this... add window object before document.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
 var el = window.document.getElementById('myTable');
 var firstHeader =  window.document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName( 'thead' )[0].getElementsByTagName( 'tr' )[0].getElementsByTagName( 'th' )[0];
}
```

Comment: nothing happened. Error is pointing to my setstate but cant find it